# Combining two string by one letter at the time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written code for two string combinations by one letter at the time:

```
def stringCombination( string1, string2, fillValue = filler):
    filler = string2[-1] if len(string1) > len(string2) else string[-1]
    return "".join(i for j in itertools.zip_longest(string1, string2, fillValue = filler) for i in j)
```

I get error filler is not defined. Tried every possible solution but I cannot make it work. Help would be very nice.
Working code should do:
Input: home, car
Output: hcoamre
If one string is longer= car+home=ch ao rme

Comment: Do you initialize the value of filler before you set fillValue = filler?

Comment: No i havent. I don't how to do

Comment: Replace `( string1, string2, fillValue=filler)` with `( string1, string2, filler)`, `string[-1]` with `string1[-1]` and `fillValue=filler` with `fillvalue=filler`. Then try again.

Comment: @AshkiKudžma Can you add expected input and output.

Comment: @nfnneil have provided input/output

Comment: @AshkiKudžma No I meant in form  of string1, string2 => output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because filler is not defined. What is filler? Is filler a string? Is filler a number? In the context of your function stringCombination you have not defined what "filler" is.

You are most likely looking for a default "fillValue" in that case your function signature should be something like:

```
def stringCombination( string1, string2, fillValue = " "):
```

Perhaps you defined "filler" as a global variable. In that case your code should look something like this:

```
DEFAULT_FILL_VALUE = " "
def stringCombination( string1, string2, fillValue = DEFAULT_FILL_VALUE):
```

I recommend instead of using "filler" for your global variable, you should use a clear capitalized name.

I am assuming of course that you want a default fill value of a space: " ". If you want a comma or something else, just replace the space with your desired character.

The other issue with your code is this line:

```
filler = string2[-1] if len(string1) > len(string2) else string[-1]
```

You have 3 parameters that are passed into your function: string1, string2 and fillValue. So in the context of your function you can ONLY manipulate string1, string2 and fillValue. Manipulating or assigning "filler" and "string" do not really make sense here, (although I feel "string" is just a typo, did you mean string1?).

If you are intentionally trying to modify filler and it is a global variable, I highly advise against doing this... this is just bad coding practice. You should capitalize all your global variables and make sure they remain constant!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I understand this question correctly, I think an elegant way to address this problem is the following given two strings `"123"` and `"456"`:

With the use of a common zip function, we can do:
`[elem[0] + elem[1] for elem in list(zip(a,b))]` to get
`['14', '25', '36']`
and then from there do:
 `result = "".join(['14', '25', '36'])` to get `"123456"`.

My intuition for this was to zip the two strings together into a list with a tuple for each element and since zip is an iterator, we can do a list comprehension on its `list` call. From there, I used an in-built `join` method.

I am aware that this only works for the case where the two strings are of equal length, but so far as I can tell, the only way to address the other two cases are with conditionals anyway.

Just some food for thought.